# Constructors in nested classes (C++)

Tags: c++, generics, data-structures, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a generic map in C++.
the class Map has an inner class of an iterator, it's defined as follows:

```
public:
Map();
Map(const Map& map);
~Map();
class Iterator {
    Map* map;
    Node* node;
public:
    Iterator(Map*);
    Iterator(const Iterator& Iterator);
    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator& operator--();
    Iterator& operator*();
    const K getKey();
    T& getData();
    const T& getData() const;
};
```

but when i try to implement the iterator constructor (or any other iterator method), Eclipse won't recoginize it or suggest it (when hitting ctrl+space) i.e when I write this:

```
template<class K, class T>
Map<K,T>::Iterator::Iterator(){ //Member declaration not found
//some code of constructing...
}
```

what do I miss?

Comment: Add self contained and small sample. Also, are we talking about eclipse issues or actual compiler warning?

Comment: What is the entire error message? And show us the code around the constructor implementation.

Comment: @TomaszKłak -  Well, eclipse warns about it and when i try to press ctrl+space i don't get the proper suggestion as I would expect.
but actually when i look for it on the console (where all the errors are printed) it's not there, but it's still bothers me that i get some sort of error, and it means something is wrong.
The entire error message is the Error i wrote.

Comment: The code as your showing us is valid. We need more context than this. Is there a line number the error message is pointing to? Show us the code *around* and including that line number please.

Comment: Something like: http://ideone.com/ZMLvy1 should be similar to what you have? You need to post more information or we're just guessing..

Comment: @0x499602D2 I know that it's a valid code, this is why i posted this here, because I'm not supposed to get this error. The error is pointing to the line: Map<K,T>::Iterator::Iterator(){

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames - Well, I tried it, still same error.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to define a default constructor for your `Iterator` class but you only declared a constructor taking a pointer to the containing class and a copy constructor. Try defining one of those or declare a default constructor.

Comment: It doesn't help, the main problem is that I don't get any suggestions